# how to make margin

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitouch

in my app i want to move objects (from touch using the code below) inside the red rectangle how to make this [image: iphone screen]

code :

```
UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:[touch view]];
if (insidethepaddle) {
    object1.center = CGPointMake(location.x, location.y - 50);
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your question, at least I could not understand what you want to achieve.

Comment: @Erik Aigner, all I want to let the object move only in red rectangle, in other word i need to limit the coordination (x,y) of the object

Answer (score 0):

Just use `CGRectContainsPoint(CGRect rect, CGPoint point)` or `NSPointInRect(NSPoint aPoint, NSRect aRect)` to test if the center is still inside, otherwise just don't update the objects `center`.

The specified `CGRect`/`NSRect` represents the frame of the red rectangle.

Comment: i used your code CGRect red = CGRectMake(40, 80, 300, 440);
 if (insidethepaddle &&  CGRectContainsPoint(red, location)) {
 
 paddle.center = CGPointMake(location.x, location.y - 50);
}
it works fine but when i go out the red the object release how csn i fix this